# find numbers to define a specific action and quotient

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $X=[-1,1]\times\mathbb{R}$.

- Find all numbers $\lambda,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with the property that 
  $$n\cdot (x,y):= (\lambda^nx,a+by+\lambda n)$$ defines an action of the additive group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.
- For the falues of $\lambda,a,b$ that you found compute the resulting quotients $X/\Gamma$.

Can somebody help me? I know the definition of a group action, etc. But how to find these numbers is a mystery...

Comment: Well if you know the definitions, did you check the axioms? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: actually, I don't know how to start, just trial and error? or are there some rules?

Comment: I wouldn't call it trail and error. You need to take care that this operation is well-defined, i.e. that $n \cdot (x,y)$ is an element of $X$. Then the axiom of a group action gives you some relations. You should write this down.

Comment: @user60589 I've got this: $m\cdot (n\cdot(x,y))=m\cdot (\lambda^nx,a+by+\lambda n)=(\lambda^{m+n}, a+c+(b+d)y+\lambda (m+n))=(m+n)\cdot (x,y)$. 

How does this give me some relations?

Comment: The second equality does not look right. You have to take $a+by+\lambda n$ as the "new $y$".

Comment: is it $m\cdot(\lambda^nx, a+by+\lambda n)=(\lambda^{m+n}x,c+ad+bdy+d\lambda n+\lambda m)$?

Comment: Where do the $c$'s and $d$'s come from?

Comment: then i'll keep guessing: $.. = (\lambda^{m+n}x, a+ab+b^2y+\lambda(bn+m))$

Comment: That looks good. Now you have to compare this with $(m+n) \cdot (x,y)$.

Comment: $a=0, b=1, \lambda=\mathbb{R}$. Correct? or are there more options..

Comment: You will get something like this: $ab+ (b^2-b)y + \lambda n( b-1) =0$. From this you see that $b^2-b$ has to be $0$ since $y$ is not fixed. So $b=0$ or $b=1$. So in the case $b=0$ you have $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda =0$.

Comment: ok thanks a lot!

Comment: But have to take care that $\lambda^n x  \in [-1,1]$. this gives a restriction on $\lambda$ when $b=1$. And $0^0$ is not defined. (So maybe you do not allow the case $b=0$)

Answer (score 1):

To check that you have a group action of $X$ you need to show that $$m\cdot (n \cdot (x,y) ) = (m+n) \cdot (x,y) \in X.  \tag{1}$$

Since $\lambda^n x$ has to be in $[-1,1]$, $\lambda$ has to be in $[-1,1]$ and because we usually do not define $0^0$ we want $\lambda \ne 0$.

So if you write out both sides of $1$ it becomes

$$ m\cdot (n \cdot (x,y) ) = (\lambda^{m+n}x, a+ b(a+by+\lambda n)+ \lambda m) $$

and

$$ (m+n) \cdot (x,y) = (\lambda^{m+n}x, a+ by + \lambda (m+n)).$$

Checking the axiom for the group action now reduces to show that
$$  ab +(b^2-b)y +\lambda n (b-1) =0.$$

Thus $b=0$ or $b=1$. Since $b=0$ implies $\lambda = 0$ we can exclude this case. So we have $b=1$, $a=0$ and $\lambda \in [-1,1]\setminus \{0\}$.

To compute the it is maybe convenient to get rid of the $\lambda$ in the second component. To do so, define
$$ n * (x,y)=  (\lambda^n x ,y+ n) $$
and $f \colon X \to X, \ (x,y) \mapsto (x,\lambda y)$, then $f\circ (n* (x,y) )= n \cdot f((x,y) )$.

For $\lambda = 1$ the quotient is just $[-1,1] \times S^1$. I havent figured out the other cases ... for $\lambda \in (0,1)$ maybe something like $[-1,1]^{cd}\times S^1$ where $[-1,1]^{cd}$ denotes $[-1,1]$ with the codiscrete toplogy. For $\lambda = -1$ you get $[0,1]\times S^1$ with say some strange neighborhoods around $\{0\} \times S^1$ since you glue $[-1,0] \times S^1$ and $[0,1]\times S^1$ with a rotation. And the last case $\lambda \in (-1,0)$ is probably some mixture of the last ones. 
**Disclaimer: It is just a guess what the quotients are, maybe it is just nonsense.**